# Expand Child When Parent IsExpanded in a TreeView

Tags: wpf, binding, treeview, datatrigger

I am attempting to expand a Child Node when its parent is expanded.

Otherwise stated: (Child.IsExpanded == Parent.IsExpanded)

This appears right, but does not seem to work:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True" 
                             Binding="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, 
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                             Mode=FindAncestor, 
                             AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}, 
                             AncestorLevel=2}}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Neither does this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
                    Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, 
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                             Mode=FindAncestor, 
                             AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}, 
                             AncestorLevel=2}}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

What's missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both work for me. If you tested it with static `TreeViewItems` make sure to apply the style via resources, the `ItemContainerStyle` is only relevant for dynamically created containers. Also note that user-interaction may set a *local value*, overriding those styles.